# Jquery: Slide images diagonally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the effect I want to achieve: [image]

This is i.e. one image, and the other images should slide diagonally in the way that arrow goes. The effect should not be fade effect. The slide effect has to be achieved.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="slider_page">
   <div style="display: block;">
       <img src="img1.jpg">                      
       <img src="img2.jpg">                 
   </div>
</div>
```

Please for help guys.

Sorry for the mess in the html code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try anyhting?

Comment: Yes i did the fade effect, but it is not what I am looking for

Comment: Are you using any library?

Comment: @mage-to Please show what you tried to achieve that effect, so we can enhance the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rough sketch on how to do it on your own, without a library. The code might need some adaption for your particular circumstances. For instance, if you want to slide not only images but elements containing text as well, change from using `<img>` to `<div>`. You'll find explanation in the comments.

**HTML**

```
<div id="carousel">
    <img class="carousel-img" src="img1.jpg" />
    <img class="carousel-img" src="img2.jpg" />
    <img class="carousel-img" src="img3.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#carousel {
    position: relative; /* So images are positioned relative to it. */
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden; /* So we clip the other images. */
}

.carousel-img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; /* Position relative to parent div. */
    left: 400px; /* Hide just beyond bottom right corner. */
    top: 300px;
}

.carousel-img:first-child {
    /* Do not hide the first image. */
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
//Some settings.
var animation_time = 500; //Millisecs the animation takes.
var waiting_time = 2000; //Millisecs between animations.

//Some variables.
var images; //A list of the images.
var i = 0; //Index of the current image.
var w; //Width of carousel.
var h; //Height of carousel.

$(function() {

    //Runs when the DOM is ready.

    //Set the variables.
    images = $("#carousel .carousel-img");
    w = $("#carousel").css("width");
    h = $("#carousel").css("height");

    //Start the carousel.
    setTimeout(slideToNext, waiting_time)    

});

function slideToNext() {

    //Get the index of the next image.
    var next = (i + 1) % images.length;

    //Make sure the new image is on top.
    images.css("z-index", 0);
    images.eq(next).css("z-index", 1);

    //Animate the next image.
    images.eq(next).animate({left: "0px", top: "0px"}, animation_time, function() {

        //Runs when the animation is compleated.

        //Move the old image out.
        images.eq(i).css({left: w, top: h});

        //Now this is the current image.
        i = next;

        //Do it again.
        setTimeout(slideToNext, waiting_time);

    });

}
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8dLmo3h/3/), including some beautiful artwork by [Caspar David Friedrich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspar_David_Friedrich).

It might also be possible to configure an existing carousel library (like [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) or [Jssor](http://www.jssor.com/index.html)) to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works and this is what I was looking for! Marked as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Hey one more question please: Can the effect be like this  http://s18.postimg.org/c56edx3xl/slide_diagonal.jpg ?

Comment: I do not know how to accomplish an effect like that using JS. But take a look at Jssor (linked in my answer), they have a collection of fansy transition effects.

Comment: Ok Anders thanks a lot again, it was very helpful to me.